# In java How can i add (+) all the results of user input values when programs end

Tags: java

public class TotalHours {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double in;
    double out;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

      String choice = "y";
    while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
    System.out.println("Enter Check in time: ");
   in = sc.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("Enter Check out time: ");
            out = sc.nextDouble();
          double calculations;
       calculations = out - in; 
        System.out.println("Total hours of the day: " +calculations);

System.out.print("Calculate another salary? (y/n): ");
        choice = sc.next();
        System.out.println();
```

/*now I want to add (+) all the results of multiple inputs user gonna put when the program ends. Let's say check-in time is: 6.30
Checkout time is: 9.30 
"Total hours of the day: 3 and then next hours comes to 4, so I want to add all total hours of the day each when program ends 
Your help would be highly appreciated.
*/

```
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Now write what didi you do.

Comment: Your question is very unclear on what the problem is you need help with, you have a loop that gets user input and have provided no way to keep track of individual day results, if the problem is you want a per day list you have to come up with a data structure  that stores the information you need at a later point, a Scanner object functions as an iterator which means it retrieves user input then moves to the next token, it does not store the information that it iterates through, if you want that functionality extend the class and use a collection type to store information.

Comment: Please format the question correctly. Use the code snippets correctly for code highlighting and provide a little more of background of your problem and where the current code is up to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean something like this:

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
 public static void main(String[] args) {

     Double calculations = 0;
     String choice = "y";
     while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
         ...
         Double innerCalculation = 0;
         innerCalculation = out - in;
         calculations += innerCalculation;
         System.out.println("Total hours of the day: " + innerCalculation);
         ...
     }
     System.out.println("Total hours of all time: " +calculations);
 }
```

Basically what we did here is we declared a variable outside the `while` scope so we can preserve it's value, it is called `calculations`, we will use it to keep the `total hours of all time`. Another thing we changed was inside `while` loop where we declared `innerCalculation` variable which contains difference between `out` and `in` variable which determine `total hours on that day`, then we add those hours to our `calculations` variable to keep updating the `total hours`, then when the user finally decides its time to stop inputting data, we will print the `total hours of all time` into the console.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's exactly what I wanted. My mistake:  I writing everything in while loop. It's not my assignment or anything This is just for my practice. Sorry for the confusion as I know my question was not clearly stated.